# Cannot use a C++ file in Xcode - Cannot Resolve Libs

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4, objective-c++

I am trying to figure out why XCode cannot resolve a C++ file I imported.

- I have changed the file extension to .mm
- I have added the .h file contents to the top of my file
- I have command line tools installed

The code complete detects the algorithm library:

[image: Code Complete Works]

But when I try compile I get this:

[image: Not working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the issue.

As it turns out you need to not only use the .mm extension to invoke the objective-c++ compiler, but also anything that REFERENCES the .mm too. So I had a view controller that referenced the c++ header.